# pinch to zoom layout with Vector images

Tags: android, kotlin, pinchzoom, gesturedetector

I have a layout which holds a FrameLayout, which in turn has a varying amount of ImageViews on top of it. (Only one is visible at any given time, and the user can flip/switch between them)
All of the ImageViews are Vector drawables.

When I try to implement the Pinch-to-zoom functionality, I encounter various problems.

With **Solution 1 :**

```
override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
     scaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor
     scaleFactor = ((scaleFactor * 100)).toInt().toFloat() / 100
     scaleFactor = max(MIN_SCALE_FACTOR, min(scaleFactor, MAX_SCALE_FACTOR))

     frameView.scaleX = scaleFactor
     frameView.scaleY = scaleFactor
     frameView.pivotX = e.x
     frameView.pivotY = e.y
}
```

Basically, I use the same logic for Double-tap zoom, and it works fine there(I'm also applying some animation to smoothen it).

However, with pinch-to-zoom, the image suffers from stuttering, especially when I keep holding two fingers on the screen, you can see how it constantly jumps around.

I tried **Solution 2 :**

which is using this OnPinchListener : https://www.dev2qa.com/android-pinch-zoom-layout-example/

But :

**1**. The example there works with a simple ImageView (NOT vector).
    When I try it with a vector drawable, the image distorts and becomes pixeled and ugly.

**2**. In my case, I need to apply the scaling(zoom) to the 
    frameView (FrameLayout holding the images), so using the "setImageBitmap" approach 
    is irrelevant here.

So basically it seems this solution cannot be used in my case.

Are there any other ways (or something that I missed in my first solution perhaps) that could make the pinch to zoom work smoothly?